# A question of real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, gre-exam

If for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(1)|\geq\epsilon $$ whenever $$|x-1|\geq\delta$$
Then which of the following is true?

A.$f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$

B.$f$ is unbounded.

C.$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$ exists.

D.$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$

I consider an example $f(x)=x$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ as we go far from $1$ also $f(x)$ goes far from $f(1)$.In this case B,D are true and A,C are false.

Comment: What is wrong with the question?Why you are voting down?

Comment: Many people object to questions that are phrased as bare problem-statements. What have you tried, and what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Now i edit the question

Comment: Similarly for $f(x)=|x|$ only option A is false and all other options are true.

Comment: And i think option B and D are equivalent.Am i right?

Comment: $B$ and $D$ are not equivalent, but $D$ implies $B$.

Comment: @T.Bongers can you give me some example in which B does not imply D?Thanks

Comment: See my answer${}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x$ serves as a counterexample to $A$, by choosing $\epsilon = \delta$. It also serves as a counterexample to $C$.

The function

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} x :& x \in \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 :& \text{ else } \end{array}\right.$$

serves as a counterexample to $D$. Note how $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily far away from $f(1)$, but is small for almost all values of $x$.